# Cipher Tool is not encrypting password

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I am using WSO2 Integration Studio 8.1.0 on Windows 10 and I have Ant installed (Apache Ant 1.10.12) and added the ANT bin directory (`ANT_HOME`) to the path system variable.

In my `deployment.toml` file which is located in `Integration_Studio_Home\runtime\microesb\conf`.

I added the following under the secrets header

```
[secrets]
admin_password  = "adminUserPassword"
```

Then opened cmd and navigated to `Integration_Studio_Home\runtime\microesb\bin`.

Then executed `ciphertool.bat -Dconfigure`

**Result** :

```
.\wso2\lib\Saxon-HE-9.5.1-8.jar
Using CARBON_HOME:   C:\WSO2\INTEGR~1\runtime\microesb\bin\..
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12

Encrypting using Internal KeyStore.
{type: JKS, alias: wso2carbon, path: repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks}

[Please Enter Internal KeyStore Password of Carbon Server : ]

Internal KeyStore of Carbon Server is initialized Successfully


Secret Configurations are written to the property file successfully
```

But when I open `deployment.toml` I find that the password under the secrets section is not encrypted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the secret value between square brackets `[]`. In your case, it should be as follows,

```ini
[secrets]
admin_password  = "[adminUserPassword]"
```

Furthermore, if you are using the embedded MI runtime, you can use the Integration Studio itself to encrypt the secrets. Have a look at [Encrypt static (embedded) server secrets](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/using-embedded-micro-integrator/#encrypt-static-embedded-server-secrets)

For more info check,

- Defining secrets - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/encrypting_plain_text/#static-secrets